# Laravel 11 with MongoDB: CSRF token doesn't work / 419 error on Login

Tags: laravel, mongodb, csrf, csrf-token, laravel-11

I have started making the Website in Laravel 11 with MongoDB as its database but got CSRF token 419 error in Admin Login form itself.

My form Action with csrf token is as below:

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/login') }}" method="post">@csrf
```

And it is giving below 419 error:

```
419 PAGE EXPIRED
```

This is the same approach I have followed in Laravel 10 but found no issue.

The only way to get rid of this issue to add the route `admin/login` in `app.php` file like below:

```
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->validateCsrfTokens(
            except: ['admin/login']
        );
    })
```

But this is not the solution and not feasible to add all routes to espace CSRF token and bypass security.

Comment: "started making the Website" did you generate the key for the salt of encryption ? run the command `php artisan key:generate` if not

Comment: Yes I run that command again but still issue is there